# Python: How to calculate the values of Precision-recall and F-measure through Singular Value Decomposition on MovieLens 1M Dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine, svd, precision-recall

I tried to calculate it using `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support` but, it gave me this error
`ValueError: Can't handle mix of multiclass-multioutput and continuous-multioutput`

Output of predicted matrix and test matrix is available in the screenshot. [Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhFVZ.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

df = pd.read_csv('/home/linux/Documents/RecommenderSystem/Datasets/MovieLens/ml-1m/ratings.dat', sep='::', names=['user_id', 'item_id', 'rating', 'timestamp'], engine='python')

n_users = df.user_id.unique().shape[0]
n_items = df.item_id.unique().shape[0]
print('Number of users = ' + str(n_users) + ' | Number of movies = ' + str(n_items) )

train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.25)

# Create two user-item matrices, one for training and another for testing
train_data_matrix = np.zeros((6040, 3952))
for line in train_data.itertuples():
    train_data_matrix[line[1]-1, line[2]-1] = line[3]

test_data_matrix = np.zeros((6040, 3952))
for line in test_data.itertuples():
    test_data_matrix[line[1]-1, line[2]-1] = line[3]

# get SVD components from train matrix. Choose k.
u, s, vt = svds(train_data_matrix, k=100)
s_diag_matrix = np.diag(s)
X_pred = np.dot(np.dot(u, s_diag_matrix), vt)
print('SVD RMSE: ' + str(sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_data_matrix, X_pred))))
print('SVD MAE: ' + str(mean_absolute_error(test_data_matrix, X_pred)))
```